# AWS cloud storage optimized for retrieval for files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, storage

I have built a file processing pipeline where a file once added to an S3 bucket will trigger 5 to 6 different lambdas. In each lambda, I am going to download the file and do some processing on it.

Here is the problem: S3 cost for downloading the file in each lambda is costing 50% of the total S3 costs incurred. Is there any way I can store the file in a cache, download the file from there into the lambdas and once the processing has completed, delete the file from the cache?

Some pointers: Each process must be done simultaneously, can't be combined into a single lambda.

The lambdas are present in the same region as the S3 bucket. In the previous month alone, we had a total of 250 million GET operations on the objects in the S3 bucket.

Comment: You can check EFS. This way once you copy file to EFS, all your lambdas can read it as is, withing the need of copying it all over again multiple times.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-a-shared-file-system-for-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: How do you calculate your S3 costs? If the Lambda function is in the same region as the S3 bucket, the only cost would be `$0.0004 per 1000 requests`. Please edit your question to include your calculations.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It is $0.004 per 1000 requests. I have edited the question to include our last month statistics

Comment: Does this mean you have 50 million objects going through the pipeline each month? That's about 20 per second? That's quite impressive! How big is each object? You could modify your system to use a cache (eg ElastiCache), by having 'something' that retrieves the object and stores it in the cache before the Lambda functions try to process it. You'd need to implement that logic yourself. For example: [Turbocharge Amazon S3 with Amazon ElastiCache for Redis | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/turbocharge-amazon-s3-with-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/)

Comment: Yes, approximately 50 million objects. Each object can be upto 4MB. Once the object has gone through all processing, it is stored in S3. Just for downloading the object 6 times, we need this caching as it is expensive with S3. Maybe ElastiCache is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the cleaner approach would be to segregate the functionality and use STEP FUNCTION offering from AWS to orchestrate the flow of execution. You can take leverage of differnet states during this orchestration. If you want to use the output of the the child lamba you can get that as well in the next lambda.

Please explore this option rather than waiting for the response from child lambda within another.

Official Documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/?step-functions.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&step-functions.sort-order=desc

Thanks!!

Comment: The processing of the file in one lambda is not dependent on the processing of the same file in another lambda